# Read CSV and perform SQL in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2012, csv

Is it possible in SQL Server Management Studio to read a CSV and perform an SQL update per line?

Example

data.csv

`"column1","column2,"column3"
 "column1","column2,"column3"
 "column1","column2,"column3"
 "column1","column2,"column3"
 "column1","column2,"column3"`

I want to run a SQL update based on the data in each line such as

`UPDATE [data].[orders] set order_number = $column1, something_else = $column2 where order = $column3`

Is this possible to do in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Look at [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(v=sql.110).aspx) and the options there. It's pretty simple actually.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off just opening this in Excel (or your chosen spreadsheet provider) and just updating it using filters?  Tip: Selecting multiple cells, typing a value and pressing `Ctrl`+`Enter` enters the same value in all cells.

Answer (score 10):

You may use [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(v=sql.110).aspx) for that:

```
CREATE TABLE #orders (
  Column1 int,
  Column2 nvarchar(max),  
  Column3 datetimeoffset
)

BULK INSERT #orders
FROM 'X:\orders.csv'
WITH
(
  FIRSTROW = 1,
  DATAFILETYPE='widechar', -- UTF-16
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
  TABLOCK,
  KEEPNULLS -- Treat empty fields as NULLs.
)
```

If you exported the CSV from SQL Management Studio then some preparations are needed:

1. The file should be converted to UTF-16.
2. All `NULL`s should be replaced with empty strings.

Here is a Powershell script for that:

```
Get-Content .\orders_raw.csv -Encoding UTF8 | % { $_ -replace "NULL","" } | Out-File ".\orders.csv"
```

Comment: FIELDTERMINATOR is ',' for .csv, otherwise this works great

Comment: It depends on the culture. In some cultures ',' is the decimal separator, therefore ';' is a safer choice.

Answer (score 3):

A simple and easy way to do this would be to import the csv into a table, then manipulate/view.
If you'd prefer a graphical method instead of using tsql; right click your database and select Tasks, and then select Import Data.

Answer (score 1):

May be [SSMS: How to import (Copy/Paste) data from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61012585/6165594) can help (If you don't want to use `BULK INSERT` or don't have permissions for it).

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to below link for how to read csv file in SQL Server:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/powersql-by-prashanth-jayaram/2015/02/09/t-sql-read-csv-files-using-openrowset/

Based on that you will be able to work with your csv data as a table and then you can create the update query as required.